# Android Fragments with compatible library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I can't make it work.

I found many similar question here, examples. But nothing help and nothing work.
Does anyone have a working Fragments in Android 2.2 with android.support.v4 library? (If you are please upload it somewhere.)

I'm almost crying because I can't find what's wrong!

The error is the same as many of people have:

```
05-15 18:20:20.583: W/dalvikvm(1521): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity; (8)
05-15 18:20:20.583: W/dalvikvm(1521): Link of class 'Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity;' failed
05-15 18:20:20.593: D/AndroidRuntime(1521): Shutting down VM
05-15 18:20:20.593: W/dalvikvm(1521): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.fragment.test/my.fragment.test.FragmentTestActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.fragment.test.FragmentTestActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/my.fragment.test-1.apk]
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.fragment.test.FragmentTestActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/my.fragment.test-1.apk]
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-15 18:20:20.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     ... 11 more
05-15 18:20:23.423: I/Process(1521): Sending signal. PID: 1521 SIG: 9
```

SOLVED!!!! Who have this warnings before error:

```
05-16 10:08:00.033: W/dalvikvm(1695): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity; (7)
05-16 10:08:00.076: W/dalvikvm(1695): Link of class 'Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity;' failed
```

Should export android-support-v4 to right to your app:

Configure Java Build Path -> Order And Export tab -> **set checkbox android-support-v4.jar**

(Maybe need to remove existing one firstly)

it will moves this library to your apk (as I understand it)

Comment: The error message says its looking for something with the name 
    my.fragment.test/my.fragment.test.FragmentTestActivity
Maybe the name should not include the complete package name?
(It just hit my eye when I looked at the error message)

Comment: Did you put FragmentTestActivity in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I put.And I've tried different ways - complete package name and simply Fragment name. Didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have 1 FragmentActivity with fragments inside. What you are doing is trying to put activities (fragmentactivity) inside xml. That wont work. Try to only have 1 top level fragmentactivity and then make the other into fragments and then put those fragments inside your xml.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are obviously just learning about this I'll expand on Warpzit's answer to try and help you out (you should accept his answer so he gets credit, since it is the correct one and he answered first).

This:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Needs to be this:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Fragment
```

As do any other tabs you want to display as part of that first activity.

There should only be one FragmentActivity unless you are going to start a second activity (and leave the first) that will also have fragments, then the same applies.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter. I don't use this second Activity right now, I can totally delete it, and error still the same

Answer (score 0):

why do you have two activities named FragmentTestActivity? or is just writing error? 
have you declared it in manifest?

Comment: just duplicate, my mistake :) it's just one FragmmentActivity in application

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace `android:name="classpath"` with `class=""classpath`.